# Unable to make React Native PushNotificationIOS work

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, expo

I'm trying to add PushNotificationIOS to my project but I'm getting the following error. I tried to build the library from its own project as well but even there it won't built and throw the same below error. I can't find any fix anywhere.

1. I linked the library manually following the official doc
2. I added the correct header search path
3. I added the correct import to  AppDelegate.m

In file included from ***/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/RCTPushNotificationManager.m:10: ***/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/RCTPushNotificationManager.h:10:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTEventEmitter.h' file not found #import

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hugo, did you ever overcome this issue? I am having it right now.

Comment: @Dan Hey I did manage to fix it by making a new project from scratch with "react native init project-name" after a lot of research without any working solutions. I'm sorry I don't have a real solution for this problem as it could be linked to hundreds of possible things... My project was messy as well I had multiple React project import and other stuff that could have caused it but I just decided to start again from scratch. Hope you'll find a solution for your problem.

Comment: No worries Hugo, thank you for the insight. I am struggling too with fixing this problem. I'm looking to start afresh too! Thanks for your comment.